# Configuring a reverse-proxy-like Firebase Hosting solution

Tags: firebase, proxy, google-cloud-functions, reverse-proxy, firebase-hosting

This is what I currently **have**

```
domain.com ->  website A with its own firebase host (domain.firebase.com)
me.domain.com -> website B with its own firebase host (domain-me.firebase.com)
```

This wasn't hard to set up, just multiple sub-domains redirecting to different Firebase hosts. Now, what I **want**, is a reverse proxy takes a request and has the option of routing traffic to various servers while keeping the client URL only on the main domain of **domain.com**. I'm not sure if this is possible *specifically with Firebase*, as there are tons of NGINX implementation examples, But basically, I want this:

```
domain.com/ ->  website A with its own firebase host (domain.firebase.com)
domain.com/me -> website B with its own firebase host (domain-me.firebase.com)
```

Firebase has very intricate redirect options, but redirects also overwrites the client URL. So with a redirect, the client will see **domain-me.firebase.com** instead of **domain.com/me**, which isn't what I want.

As far as I've figured, I can use Firebase Cloud functions to serve as a middleware, and have it serve either site as needed. However, this introduces a lot of latency as both Cloud functions and Firebase hosted websites have warm-up times from cold starts.

It's totally fine to not give me a complete and detailed answer, I really just want to know if this is possible to begin with, and where I can find relevant resources. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question and building on Doug's answer of using Cloud Run. There is a quick and painless way to set up a reverse-proxy-like implementation with 2 apps. To do this:

1) Build both apps and have them in separate folders, such as folder A and folder B. **You only need the build folders of the apps, you don't need the source code.**

2) Create a new Express app at the root of folders A and B.

3) Have Express manage routes using app.get and serve files back using res.sendFile.

4) Containerize the entire Express app following Google's tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy), you can ignore the sample application since your new Express app *is* the application.

5) Upload to Cloud Run as a new service. Keep in mind that while the Google tuts don't specify, you **will** need to give your user permission to upload to the storage bucket. You will need the command 
`gsutil iam ch user:[user]:objectViewer gs://us.artifacts.[project-name].appspot.com`
Also make sure to switch to the current project using command `gcloud config set project [project-name]` if you have multiple projects.

6) Use Google domain mapping to map to your **root** domain, so `domain.com`.

You **must** use domain mapping as the URL used by Cloud Run is ephemeral...'cause it's serverless.

Your folder structure should be something like

```
my-awesome-project
    index.js <- Express app and Docker entry point
    /package.json <- for your Express app
    /A
    /B
    /Dockerfile
    /node_modules
```

Example router would be

```
app.get('/me/*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/B/index.html'));
});

app.get('/*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/A/index.html'));
});
```

Setting your apps up on subdomains instead works pretty much the same way. Containerize each individual app using step 4, then map each domain separately using Google Domain Mapping.

Comment: How does your firebase.json look?

Comment: I retired that project, but I didn't think I had one. I ran the project with Express; I think firebase.json is only needed if you're using firebase to handle the routes.

Answer (score 1):

Integration with [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) and [Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run) are pretty much your only options here.  There's nothing in the config that will let you proxy your requests directly to other endpoints other than indirectly through [HTTP redirects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know I said I didn't mind if the answer wasn't complete, but I see that you work on the Firebase team. First, I want to clarify what I've read. In short, I have both of my current hosted sites as containerized images uploaded to Cloud Run(which basically acts as Firebase Hosting when it deploys them to the user), then I use Firebase Cloud Functions to route the image to the user, correct? Second, what are the delays/latency for this? FCFs have warmup times inherently, does Firebase Run also have long warmup times?

Comment: If you have questions beyond what you originally asked, please research them and post separately as different questions.  Network latency can *never* be guaranteed.

Comment: I've listed my questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548947/implementing-cloud-run-with-firebase-cloud-functions

Comment: Thanks for the help Doug, I've posted my steps to get everything up and running.