# Implementing Cloud Run with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

After reading the docs on both Cloud Run and Firebase Cloud Functions, I have a few questions I want to clear up:

1. Does Cloud Run basically act as a container image storage/deploying mechanism? If I have 2 websites and have them as separate containerized images, does Cloud Run just deploy the specified one given the trigger?
2. Integrating Cloud Run with Firebase Cloud Functions as the trigger, will there be an additional layer of latency? While latency times are never known, FCFs inherently have warm-up times due to cold starts, will there be added latency due to Cloud Run cold-starting the images?
3. Does the Cloud Run images travel through the FCF to get to the user. Or does FCF merely redirect the user directly to the Cloud Run image?

   Basically, is it like

   ```
   Client -> FCF -> Image -> FCF -> Client
   ```

   or

   ```
   Client -> FCF -> Image -> Client
   ```

Comment: I usually think of Cloud Functions as serving up microservices where you supply the code and Google provides the environment in which your code runs.   I see Cloud Run as a newer alternative to Cloud Functions but essentially performing the same task.  The distinction being that the framework in which your code runs is more under your control and can be "richer" than Cloud Functions.  I'm not seeing why/how one would ever execute Cloud Run (as the desired endpoint) by first routing through Cloud Functions.  What do you see as the reason/benefit?

Comment: According to my understanding, Cloud Run deploys images based on triggers, so I was assuming FCFs were needed as kind of a "router" to trigger different images based on the route. Given a single domain, it will redirect to the FCF "router", which then serves the Cloud Run images.

Answer (score 1):

Typically on Stack Overflow one is supposed to limit to one question per post (to avoid being closed as "too broad"), but I'll try here.  Please address followup questions as new posts.

1. Yes, it is just a containerized way of serving HTTP requests.
2. Cloud Run is not directly related to Cloud Function except where you write code to connect them.  If you write a Cloud Function trigger that proxies to Cloud Run, it will incur all the latency costs of both products, as required (not all invocations require a cold start).  All "serverless" compute options have a cold start time, since they all scale down to zero (based on current load), and you don't pay for virtual server instances to be allocated and immediately available all the time.
3. Again, they are not related.  You can use either one without the other.

Comment: Thanks for the second reply, Doug. I didn't want to spam the Firebase stackoverflows with 4 questions in 2 hours, so I tried to compact my posts. To clarify question 3, I want to know specifically in my use case, or rather as a FCF use case. When using Cloud Run and FCF together, does FCF basically dispatch a call to Cloud Run? Or does it tell Cloud Run to deploy the image, then return whatever data is in the image?

Comment: As I said, the products are not directly related at all.

Comment: On 3) If you use Cloud Functions (from Firebase or separately) Cloud Run is not involved in any way.